# vue create fails with ERR_ASSERTION

Tags: vue.js

Running `vue create my-project` fails with

```
assert.js:92
  throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 293 == 0
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users\myname\.node_modules_global\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:160:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:490:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23) {
  generatedMessage: true,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: 293,
  expected: 0,
  operator: '=='
}
```

while node & npm install can be run just fine. I'm behind a corporate proxy, my versions are 
@vue/cli 4.5.11 
node v12.14.1
npm 6.14.8
I can ping https://registry.npmjs.org/ without problems. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing vue cli 5.0.0-alpha.3 via `npm install -g @vue/cli@5.0.0-alpha.3`.
It was asking to change to TaobaoRegistry since https://registry.npmjs.org/ appeared to be slow. Maybe the current stable does not cover this.